# Rails 4 Devise - Adding a new route and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Devise for authentication and have the below in my routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
```

I want to add a new page under users and have another form in there to collect additional user input. There is lot of info on this on SO but most of it seems too complicated. I'm guessing this should be one or two lines of code? Say I want to add a url users/additionalinfo and the related method to the controller (devise methods are in my application_controller.rb). How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
 devise_scope :users do
   get '/my_controller/additionalinfo', :to => 'my_controller#additionalinfo'
 end
```

I don't think it's that complicated. Please check the devise doc for more info: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: I did what you said `devise_scope :users do get '/users/bankacc', :to => 'application#bankacc' end` and under that I have `devise_for :users`. When I go to the URL, I get an Unknown Action error saying `The action 'bankacc' could not be found for ApplicationController`. I have a blank method `def bankacc end` in my application_controller and a view file in my devise folder.

Comment: I guess its not a routing issue. As error says The action could not be found, maybe a typo or something? Please check if method name is proper as what you have defined, on the other hand, you can say: `rake routes` to see if this route has been created or not.